# react-native-vector-icons don't work in Expo project

Tags: icons, expo

I installed react-native-vector-icons in my Expo project.
But it doesn't work.

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';
```

it shows this error 
[image]

This is package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "antd-mobile": "^2.1.8",
    "expo": "^27.0.1",
    "firebase": "^4.13.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "native-base": "^2.4.3",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-27.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-countdown": "0.0.3",
    "react-native-countdown-clock": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-countdown-hint": "^0.0.3",
    "react-native-render-html": "^3.9.3",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-swiper-flatlist": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-timeago": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.11",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.11"
  }
}
```

I installed packages by `yarn install` and tried `npm install`
but both not worked

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if this works.

`import SimpleLineIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';`

Answer (score 0):

For ios :
https://medium.com/@vimniky/how-to-use-vector-icons-in-your-react-native-project-8212ac6a8f06
For android I just solved the issue using:

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

this line paste into android/app/build.gradle(app). then re-run android.